# display: table-cell with text-align: center

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, centering

I'm working on a slide-in, full screen navigation type of set up and everything is working fairly well (although I'm absolutely open to ideas to improve the concept!). My issue is center-aligning the text in the vertically aligned div. I've tried the usual text-align: center on each of the ul, li, a and a div in the provided pen, but nothing jives.

I tried adding a div in the li using the following, but it just didn't work as intended:

```
ul li a {
  display: table;
  height: 25vh;
}

ul li a div {
  display: table-cell;   
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/robotsmeller/pen/OWOxor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add

```
ul li a {
  line-height: 25vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

see updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRxQrm

hope it helps

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That did it. So stupid that I missed that... :/ Cheers mate!

Comment: One further thought - any idea why the div is no longer clickable as a link? I'd like to be able to click anywhere on the div to trigger the reverse slide.

Comment: @robotosmeller if you make your anchor tag as `display: block` it will work  as you want

Comment: Right you are - vertical align not even needed with the line-height present. Nice, thanks bud!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ul li div a {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```